# "screen" is not defined

Tags: python

im just started learning python with Python crash course

and there is code in this book, but it’s not working, or probably i’m missing smt

in line `self.ship = Ship(screen)` there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\first_step.py", line 40, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\first_step.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(screen)
                     ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined. Did you mean: 'self.screen'?
```

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        The function initializes the Pygame module and sets up the game window.
        """
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height)
        )
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(screen)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            # Отслеживание событий клавиатуры и мыши
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            # При каждом проходе цикла перерисовывается экран
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()
            # Отображение последнего прорисованного экрана
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Создание экземпляра и запуск игры
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

code for Ship

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    """Класс для управления кораблем"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Инициализация корабля и его начально позиции"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        # Загружает изображение корабля и получает прямоугольник
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Отрисовка корабля"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

of course i tried what is suggest
but there are more errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space
Invaders\first_step.py", line 40, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\first_step.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self.screen)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\ship.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'pygame.surface.Surface' object has no attribute 'screen'
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? `NameError: name 'screen' is not defined. Did you mean: 'self.screen'?`

Comment: ofc, edited post at the end

Comment: `ai_game` *is* `self.screen`. Why are you adding another `.screen` there?

Comment: Maybe you meant `Ship(self)`.

Comment: Using type annotations will help you use the right arguments when you call functions.

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. There are complete versions of this project available, at every stage of development. I posted these versions because it's helpful sometimes to see the whole program listings, rather than the parts that can fit on a page in a book. Here's the links for the chapter 12 listings for the [second edition](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_12), and the [third edition](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_3e/tree/main/chapter_12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the `Ship` class is instantiated correctly within the `AlienInvasion` class. It seems the `ai_game` object passed to the `Ship` class does not include the expected `screen` attribute.

For resolution, when creating an instance of the `Ship` class within the `AlienInvasion` class, pass the instance of `AlienInvasion` itself. For instance:

```py
self.ship = Ship(self)
```

Passing `self` as an argument provides the `AlienInvasion` object to the `Ship` class, allowing access to its attributes, including the `screen` attribute. This modification should resolve the `AttributeError` related to the missing `screen` attribute.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\first_step.py", line 40, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\first_step.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self.screen)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Куку\Desktop\Space Invaders\ship.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'pygame.surface.Surface' object has no attribute 'screen'```

Comment: I've updated the solution. Try it